# Use Java Registered Client Authentication Certificates in OkHttpClient Handshake

Tags: java, ssl, okhttp, tls1.2

I have some Client Authentication Handshake Certificates registered with the Java JRE.

If I use `java.net.HttpURLConnection` to make the connection, it is successful.

However, if I use the **OkHttpClient**, I get a *401*, for not sending the Cert.

How do I get OkHttpClient to use the JRE / OS Registered Certs?

Comment: It should be, please raise an issue at https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues with a reproduction.  There are example servers you can hit here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095559/https-test-server-that-checks-client-certificates